# How to test whether an OpenVPN tunnel was established?

Tags: openvpn

To test an OpenVPN tunnel setup I need to detect when a newly started OpenVPN daemon **has established a tunnel** (or tried and **failed** to do so) before trying to send something over the tunnel.

Comment: Sorry to bring back such an old thread but I'm also interested in whatever solution works for you now in regards to OpenVPN and determining if a connection is up or down.

Comment: The listed solution was the one used in the end, since there were no better suggestions to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on an excellent way to [timeout `tail`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041504/96588):

```
ssh hostname '
    sleep 5 &
    timerPID=$!;
    tail -n0 -F --pid=$timerPID /var/log/messages | grep openvpn | while read -r line;
    do
        if echo "$line" | grep -qF -e "Initialization Sequence Completed" -e "Connection refused";
        then
            kill $timerPID;
            break;
        fi;
    done &
    /etc/init.d/openvpnA start &
    wait $timerPID'
```

That is:

1. Connect to the VPN client or server

   1. Start a timer asynchronously
   2. Collect log lines asynchronously containing `openvpn` until the timer dies

      1. Look for signs that the connection succeeded or was refused

         1. Kill the timer
         2. Exit the loop
   3. Start the daemon
   4. Wait for the timer to die

It seems to work, but being unfamiliar with OpenVPN I'm not sure if this is the correct way to detect the connection status. Since I'm the only one using the machine I think the possibility of a timing issue resulting in the `grep` succeeding because of an earlier process startup can be ignored. But I'm guessing only someone familiar with the OpenVPN code can really answer this: *Is the current test sufficient to establish whether the connection was successful or refused?*