# Getting the pid of a process present at the start of pipe

Tags: java, shell, pipe

I have a shell script that runs a Java process p1 and also there's a non-Java process p2 that takes input from p1.

How can I get process id of p1?

I have a shell script that works unpredictably (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).
I have browsed the net but none of the answers seem perfect.

My script:

```
nohup sh -c "exec java p1 | p2 2>&1" &
$pid=`echo $!`
my_pid=exec ps -eo "%p %c %P" | awk -v p=$pid 'p==$3{print $1 $2}' | grep java | sed -e 's/java//'

echo "my_pid $my_pid"
```

Comment: Why do you need the process ID if your other process just needs to read from the first?  Can you just pipe the output of `p1` into `p2`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the PID of a process in a pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345460/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-in-a-pipeline)

Comment: @TomAnderson Yes i have seen that.

Comment: @TomAnderson Yes i have seen that.
The recommended solution of named pipes doesn't work for me, my process p1 is a long running process and that can be terminated only later by reading the pid file and calling "kill pid". 
Using the named pipe causes my command to get stuck.
I was not able to run `job -p`

Comment: You might have trouble with `jobs -p` because of the `exec` you're doing. Not sure. However, there are other answers there which don't involved named pipes or `jobs`.

Comment: a simple error in the script above seem like $pid=`echo $!`. That is, to assign a value to a variable, use: "var=..." rather than "$var=..". Also why backticking, why not simply "pid=$!" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified version of [mmd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735391/116639) from the question i linked to:

```
{ java p1 & echo $! >&2; } | p2 2>&1 &
```

This prints the PID of p1 on standard error. You also get a message from the shell telling you that the echo command has finished, but you can ignore that.

Comment: Ok i figured out my problem, after starting the parent process , i was calling my script directly. At that time the child processes were not spawn. I have added a sleep

nohup sh -c "exec java p1 | p2 2>&1" &
$pid=`echo $!`
sleep 5
my_pid=exec ps -eo "%p %c %P" | awk -v p=$pid 'p==$3{print $1 $2}' | grep java | sed -e 's/java//'

echo "my_pid $my_pid"


How can i use wait instead of sleep?

Comment: I can't read all that in a comment. Either add it to the question, or, better, ask a new question. Even better, ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ , which is specialised in this sort of stuff.