# Get the pid of a command whose output is piped

Tags: linux, bash, pid

In order to remotely start a program, log its output and immediately see that log, I'm using this script:

```
nohup mycommand 2>&1 | tee -a server.log &
```

Now, I would like to store in a file the pid of the newly started mycommand (whose name is very generic, I can't just use pgrep as there would be a risk of collision).

If I just add `echo $! > mycommand.pid` I get the pid of `tee`.

How can I reliably write the pid of `mycommand` to a file ?

And by the way, why doesn't this give the right pid ?

```
( nohup mycommand 2>&1 ; echo $! > mycommand.pid ) | tee -a server.log &
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345460/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-in-a-pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this simple variant works :

```
( nohup mycommand 2>&1 & echo $! > mycommand.pid ) | tee -a server.log &
```

I'm not sure why the `;` didn't work and why I have to use `&` instead.

Comment: I just accepted my answer because it's been 3 months. But if somebody writes a better answer with a solid explanation, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: I think the ; didn't work because it means wait for the first command to finish - at which point the pid is gone?