# Event not found error

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute the below command.

```
ssh node1 "nohup sleep 66 &; echo $!"
```

But I am getting the error:

```
-bash: !": event not found
```

Comment: I need to store the process id to check the status later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh node1 'Pgrep -f sleep 66'
```

solved the issue

Comment: Please extend your answer: Why does your answer solve the question?

Comment: storing the value of the above command in variable that will store the process id of sleep 66 . And we can check the process id status using variable anytime. The pupose of question was to store the process id of remote machine in variable.  so we can use:1) ssh node1 `nohup sleep 66 &`     2) x(variable)=`ssh node1 'pgrep -f sleep 66'

Answer (score 2):

You should use single quotes to prevent interpretation of the `$!`:

```
ssh node1 'nohup sleep 66 &; echo $!'
```

It also looks like the `;` isn't useful here. This seems to work:

```
ssh node1 'nohup sleep 66 & echo $!'
```

Comment: bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `nohup sleep 66 &; echo $!'

Comment: Not working with single quotes also

Comment: @Ravikanth I've had a similar problem. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754469/get-the-pid-of-a-command-whose-output-is-piped