# ! in a string makes it unusable in a command line - error message "event not found"

Tags: bash, shell

This is a quite simple question that I can't find an answer to.

I have a string such as "ASDGFasd#!dasd" which I would like to enter into the command line as an argument e.g.

```
python test.py "ASDGFasd#!dasd"
```

This does not run test.py with the string provided (as I want it to), but instead returns:

```
bash: !dasd: event not found
```

How do solve this?

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with python 2.7

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double?

Comment: Yep, that did it, if you make that comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: That's history expansion biting you. You can use single quotes as TomZych said or disable it. This should not be a problem in a script (as history expansion is disabled in non-interactive shell sessions by default).

Comment: Go ahead and take the answer, @Etan. You knew what it was, I only knew how to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah but good luck finding either of these if you don't know it's history expansion :) I'll change the title to reflect the error message, making this more searchable.

Comment: A couple more: [29744748](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744748) [26443880](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443880).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll attempt a summary of existing answers to similar questions:

- **`!`** is expanded by **`bash`** as part of the ***history expansion* feature**, which is **by default *on* in *interactive* shells, but *off* by default in *scripts*** (non-interactive shells).

  - Specifically, `!` *together with the following characters* is interpreted as an expression that recalls a *previous command*; e.g., `!!` recalls the most recently executed command, and `!l` recalls the most recently executed command starting with `l`.
- An **easy way to avoid expansion of `!` altogether is to turn history expansion *off***, which is advisable, given that the feature can be disruptive and given that the `readline` library's features, which were introduced later, are a superior replacement.

  - To turn history expansion off, add **`set +H`** (or `set +o histexpand`) to your `~/.bashrc` file (or `~/.bash_profile` file on OS X) - this is recommended in the highest-voted answer to "[-bash: !": event not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443880)"
  - An alternative, though probably ill-advised, is to choose an *alternative* character for history expansion, by setting the special `histchars` shell variable to the desired character.

---

With history expansion ON, **`!` is expanded**:

- **always**:

  - in *unquoted* strings: `echo hi!`
  - in *double-quoted* strings, *irrespective of embedded command substitutions*: `echo "hi!"`

    - Note that this means that *`!` is even expanded inside a single-quoted string inside a command substitution embedded in a double-quoted string*: apparently, history expansion occurs very early during parsing, before the internals of the double-quoted strings are parsed to recognize embedded command substitutions; e.g.: 
      `echo "$(echo 'hi!')" # '!' is still expanded(!)` - this is the gist of question "[How to escape history expansion exclamation mark ! inside a double quoted " command substitution like "$(echo '!b')"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125658/how-to-escape-history-expansion-exclamation-mark-inside-a-double-quoted-comm)"
    - Strictly speaking, `!` parsing doesn't even respect double-quotes per se, and considers any run of non-whitespace characters following `!` the history-expansion argument, including `"`; for instance, `echo foo!"` - despite imbalanced double-quotes - is considered a valid command, as is `echo foo!bar"baz`.
- **never**:

  - in *single-quoted* strings: `echo 'hi!'`