# PID of compound shell command

Tags: bash, shell, pid

In your shell (bash in my case), you can get the pid of the last backgrounded process with the $! variable:

```
command &
echo $!
```

However, I'm interested in a compound command:

```
commandA | commandB &
echo $!
```

In this case, the value of $! seems to be the PID of commandB.  What I'm looking for is the PID of commandA.  Is there an easy way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this question:
[How to get the PID of a process that is piped to another process in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652680/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-that-is-piped-to-another-process-in-bash)

You should find what you need there.

Comment: I did find some good ideas there, thought ultimately I just went with a "ps | grep | awk" solution for pulling the pid of the first process in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

`jobs -l` will list the PIDs of each member of the pipeline.