# Why does the Rails.logger write to the same log file in development and test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have the following model test:

```
  describe 'Checking for errors' do
    it 'should check for any jobs that have errors and log them' do
      logger = Logger.new('log/go_job_errors_test.log')
      code_location = create(:code_location_with_best_code_set)
      code_location.jobs << create(:complete_job, status: 3, exception: 'I failed to complete')
      CodeLocationJobFeeder.create(code_location_id: code_location.id, url: code_location.repository.url, status: 2)
      CodeLocationJobFeeder.check_for_errors(1)
      logger.expects(:info).with("I failed to complete")
    end
```

With the following model code:

```
def check_for_errors(amount)
  processed.limit(amount).each do |code_location_job_feeder|
    code_location = CodeLocation.includes(:jobs).find(code_location_job_feeder.code_location_id)
    log_error(code_location) unless code_location.jobs.last.status != 3
  end
end

private

def log_error(code_location)
  logger = Logger.new('log/go_job_errors.log')
  failed_job = code_location.jobs.last
  logger.info do
    "Job #{failed_job.id} with code location: #{code_location.id} failed. Exception: #{failed_job.exception}"
  end
end
```

The gist of the test is that when I execute `CodeLocationJobFeeder.check_for_errors` I'll have a separate log file that will tell me all the info that I want concerning some errors. This works fine in development and I get the file that I want. However when I run the test, I get output in both `log/go_job_errors_test.log` and `log/go_job_errors.log` with the following output:

```
log/go_job_errors.log

[2017-06-28T18:23:46.164141 #29604]  INFO -- : Job 40 with code location: 93 failed. Exception: I failed to complete
```

This is the content that I want but in the wrong file. Here is the second file:

```
 log/go_job_error_test.log

 # Logfile created on 2017-06-28 18:40:59 +0000 by logger.rb/47272
```

The correct file with the wrong content.

I've been trying to apply this s.o. answer [Logger test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770552/how-to-get-rails-logger-printing-to-the-console-stdout-when-running-rspec/32628272#32628272) but it doesn't seem to be working too great. Can someone help point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because the logger you create in your tests is ignored. Nobody uses it. Model writes to its own logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line "Logger.new('log/go_job_errors.log')" in the model instructs to log model errors to this file 'log/go_job_errors.log'. Irrespective of environment, the model errors are always logged here 'log/go_job_errors.log'

In your tests, you start with this line 'Logger.new('log/go_job_errors_test.log')', this line creates a new log file. And when your test calls the model, the model calls 'log_error(code_location)', but that method only logs to 'log/go_job_errors.log'.