# Debug in headless Chrome

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara, headless

After switching from `capybara_webkit` to `headless_chrome`, I'm trying to find a way to replicate

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.debug = true
end
```

or

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_debug
```

with the new driver.
The goal is to be able to see the log of everything happening when running `rspec my_spec.rb`: for example, all `GET requests`.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: The server in 'test' env writes logs into `test.log` by default. For printing logs to console read that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770552/how-to-get-rails-logger-printing-to-the-console-stdout-when-running-rspec

Comment: Hey @Leo I'm not using Rails, so I suppose that this solution won't work, will it?

Comment: Yes, won't work. Also, in your app, you write some logs? Why doesn't that work for rspec?

Comment: The specs are independent from the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option when using Selenium like the `capybara_webkit` debug option that outputs the debug info in realtime, however you can get access to the `Chrome` logs and output those at the end of each test (or you could write a helper to output them whenever you call it of course).

First you'd need to configure your selenium driver for logging

```
Capybara.register_driver :logging_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    # customize this based on which and what level logs your prefer
    loggingPrefs: { 
      browser: 'ALL',
      driver: 'ALL',
      performance: 'ALL'
    }
  )
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()
  browser_options.headless!
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: caps,
    options: browser_options
  )
end
```

Then you'd set up to use that driver

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :logging_chrome # possibly default_driver = depending on your config
```

and then add an after block that gets the logs and displays them

```
after(:each) do
  # customize based on which type of logs you want displayed
  log_types = page.driver.browser.manage.logs.available_types
  log_types.each do |t|
     puts t.to_s + ": " + page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(t).join("\n")
  end
end
```