# Show STDOUT when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, stdout

When I run `bundle exec rspec`, I only get reports of failing tests, but no standard output (from something like `puts`, unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770552/how-to-get-rails-logger-printing-to-the-console-stdout-when-running-rspec)).

I do not want to test what is printed, I simply want to see it to understand what is going on.
Isn't there a flag to simply print this interlined?

Comment: Is stdout being silenced / redirected?

Answer (score 1):

Check your logging file, like

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commend by Stefan said, look for some code that might be redirecting or silencing stdout. I just had the same problem, and turns out my project had this code:

```
def initialize_print
  @previous_stdout = $stdout
  @previous_stderr = $stderr
  $stdout = StringIO.new
  $stderr = StringIO.new
end

def finalize_print
  unless passed?
    STDOUT.puts $stdout.string if $stdout.string
    STDERR.puts $stderr.string if $stderr.string
  end
  $stdout = @previous_stdout
  $stderr = @previous_stderr
end
```

And then every test called these in `setup`/`teardown`. It was tricky to find because it was defined in various places, and one of them was a gem external to the project, so look for it because it might not be obvious at first glance.